# Meaning of にして in these sentences

Tags: grammar

From what I understand, にして can mean  "and" or it stresses a period of time during which something happens. However, I found some sentences where the meaning of にして is totally different, and so, I am not sure if I understood correctly the meaning of にして.

> この曲はベ一ト一ベンのような天才にしてはじめて書ける作品だ。
>
> プロの職人にして失敗をするのだ。君がうまくいかなくてもしょうがないだろう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [デジタル大辞泉 entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166889/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6/) for にして, it has two separate derivations which are used in different ways. There is the form derived from the indirect object particle に, which is the usage you mentioned that can indicate a place or time, and there is the form derived from the old copula なり, which is roughly equivalent in meaning to modern であって, and covers the "and" meaning you mention.

In this case, I think we're looking at two slightly different usages of the であって sense. In the first usage, ベ一ト一ベンのような天才**であって**はじめて would convey the same meaning of "only one who is a genius like Beethoven (could write such a composition)", and the latter usage could be rephrased as プロの職人**であっても**失敗をするのだ (であって on its own doesn't really work, but I guess the にして form itself has enough of an emphatic nuance that the も is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

> Nishite (or にし)
>       1. only; just because​
>       2. although; even​
>       3. at (place, time); in (time span)​

According to Jisho.